# external jars to GWT Maven project

Tags: java, gwt, jar, import, external

I have an external jar which has *.class files that I need for my gwt project
I am trying to import them in this project but i have this error

[ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; did you forget to inherit a required module?

How can I do this?

Comment: What class/jar are your using?

Comment: Its a custom jar file

Comment: If you are using it client side that is converted to JavaScript by GWT compiler. Is your custom jar classes are able to convert into JavaScript? Is GWT compiler understand it?

Comment: No they are not being converted. I inserted a file xxx.gwt.xml to my jar file so that GWT Compiler could understand those classes but it can not.

Comment: facing same problem is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

Please check external jar. That should support by GWT otherwise it gives `did you forget to inherit a required module` error.

> GWT supports only a small subset of the classes available in the Java 2 Standard and Enterprise Edition libraries, as these libraries are quite large and rely on functionality that is unavailable within web browsers. To find out exactly which classes and methods are supported for core Java runtime packages, see the GWT [JRE Emulation Reference](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).